# Create a linear trend line in Excel graphs with logarithmic scale

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I I have an Excel scatter chart with *x* and *y* values.
I set the logarithmic scale in *x*-axis and *y*-axis.

When I add a linear trend line to the graph, the line is not linear but appears like a curve.

How can I make a linear trend line on a logarithmic-scaled chart?

Sample data:

```
x:
18449
22829
25395
36869
101419
125498
208144
2001508
14359478
17301785

y:
269,09
273,89
239,50
239,50
175,13
176,73
151,94
135,15
131,55
121,55
```

Comment: convert x,y values to logarithmic scale to some table and plot/regress the converted data

Comment: @pnuts You should post that as an answer so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a Power Trendline seems to have worked. [tusham](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/56873-power-trendline-equation.html) has kindly saved me the trouble of explaining why:

> The power trendline is given by y=c*x^b. Believe it or not, you can use LINEST to calculate the parameters. Here's how.
>
> Take the log of the above equation to get ln(y)=ln(c)+b*ln(x). This is a linear equation!

and

> A log-log *display* of the data doesn't change the underlying analysis. If you plot a bunch of X,Y pairs and ask for a power trendline, you will get the same result irrespective of whether the plot shows either or both of the axes on a log scale.